# angular directive doesn't appear in the view but appear in the console

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

i have code like below, the code is an angular directive. The code is used to calculate the distance between two places by using coordinates, my problem is the directive result (`scope.hasil = dist`) doesn't appear in the view but appear in the console (`console.log(dist)`). What should I do so that the results can appear on view ? thanks :)

**directive**

```
dir.directive('distance', function () {
var calcRoute = function(ori,dest,cb) {
        var dist;
        var directionsDisplay;
        var directionsService = new google.maps.DirectionsService();
        directionsDisplay = new google.maps.DirectionsRenderer();
    var request = {
        origin:ori,
        destination:dest,
        travelMode: google.maps.DirectionsTravelMode.DRIVING
    };
    directionsService.route(request, function(response, status) {
        if (status == google.maps.DirectionsStatus.OK) {
            directionsDisplay.setDirections(response);
            cb(null, response.routes[0].legs[0].distance.value / 1000);
        }
        else {
            cb("error");
        }
    });
};
return{
    restrict:"E",
    scope: true,
    template:"{{hasil}} km",
    link: function(scope, elm, attrs) {
       var ori = attrs.ori;
       var dest = attrs.dest;
       calcRoute(ori,dest, function (err, dist) {
            if (!err) {
              scope.hasil = dist;
              console.log(dist);
            }else{
                scope.hasil = err;
            }
    });
  }
 };
});
```

**view**

```
<distance ori="-7.048443, 110.441022" dest="-7.048264, 110.440388"></distance>
```

Comment: have you tried to wrap the `calcRoute` callback with a `scope.$apply()`

Comment: @Dario thank you..its solved my problem.. :))

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [`$scope.$apply`](https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/type/$rootScope.Scope#$apply) to refresh the view after changing the property:

```
scope.$apply(function () {
    scope.hasil = dist;
});
```

When the `link` function is called, the DOM is actually populated already. So changing the `scope` value will not re-render the DOM by default. Use `$apply` will trigger another `$digest` cycle and update the view.

Comment: thanks, its solved my problem, just like Dario said above..thank you all.. :))

Answer (score 1):

@joy's answer is probably the most correct.  Additionally a trick my team takes advantage of to have $apply run automatically is to use $timeout like so:

```
$timeout(function() {
    calcRoute(ori,dest, function (err, dist) {
            if (!err) {
              scope.hasil = dist;
              console.log(dist);
            }else{
                scope.hasil = err;
            }
    });
});
```

Comment: Yes. Because `$timeout` will call `$apply` internally. Same for `$interval`, `ng-click` etc.

Comment: i use @joy answer to wrap the `scope.hasil = dist;` with `scope.$apply` and it works.. :)